# having issue with background-image not showing

Tags: javascript, html, css

My background-image isn't showing and its driving me crazy as I know it's something easy.

The div class below is where I'm trying to get the background to show.

```
.sun-face{
    background-image: url("./images/Sun_face.svg");
}


<div class="sun-face"></div>
```

My file directory is structured like so.

```
ROOT
    -css
    -fonts
    -images
    -js
    index.html
    navbar.html
    signin.html
```

Comment: try this background-image: url("images/Sun_face.svg");

Comment: .sun-face{} that can be present in index.html file. right?

Comment: ye I have the div in signin.html

Comment: okay see demo http://jsfiddle.net/boopathirajan/3UZPF/

Comment: I have looked at the demo, I looked at w3c and follwed that even, I'm even at work doing background images all the time but its my lunch break and Im working on my own side project and I can't get it to work, I followed your fiddle no luck :/

Comment: Check your image format i think it is related to the MIME types

Comment: Use single quotes, it just looks better, and is easily. Also try using  a absolute web path and see if it works that way and not a issue with the CSS parsing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use this css

```
.sun-face{
background-image: url("../images/Sun_face.svg");
height:500px;
}
```

Comment: I added it as an inline style <style></style> it worked however if I have it in my css it doesn't

Comment: index, css, images are in same level as per the directory structure so if you use in line style "images/Sun_face.svg" would work if use a css stylesheet then you need to go with "../images/Sun_face.svg" to satisfy the directory hierarchy

Answer (score 0):

I've had this problem before and it was caused by a mime-type server issue. Basically the server wasn't configured to serve .svg files. Check your console, generally if this is the case you'll see something like 'Resource interpreted as image but transferred with MIME type...'. This can be fixed by adding a few lines the .htaccess file on your server. See this [css-tricks article](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/htaccess/serve-svg-correct-content-type/).

Answer (score 0):

So I added it in an inline style sheet,

this works, however I want it in my css file

```
 <style>
    .sun-face{
        background-image: url("./images/Sun_face.svg");
        height:500px;
        width:100%:
    }
    </style>


<link href="./css/custom.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

I put it in ^^ doesn't work?

Comment: Try this `background-image: url("../images/Sun_face.svg");`. you are missing a ".", check the url to the image.

Comment: Add the above in your css file

Comment: Thank lord, .sun-face{
    background-image: url("../images/Sun_face.svg");
    height:500px;

}